# Is there an iPhone 4 car kit for charging, music, and hands-free calls?

Tags: iphone, music, charging, audio

Is there an iPhone 4 compatible Car Kit which supports charging, playing Music through the car stereo + Hands Free Calls?

I've looked at a few kits, eg from Parrot but not many (if any?) seems to be iPhone 4/iOS4 compatible?

I currently have my iPhone plugged into my stereo, but since I upgraded to iPhone it no longer charges which is why I need to upgrade.

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 2):

If you already happy with your connection and the only main problem is the **Not Charging** part, I would strongly suggest that you contact the creators of your connector and ask for an upgrade as it is a simple power problem as the new iPhone 4 needs different Amps to charge correctly.

If you want a new connection, **I know** [Dension](http://www.dension.com/) is very good on this and integrates well with several brands of vehicles so you can use your radio to also see music details.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this gadget very successfully: [http://www.amazon.com/Satechi-Bluetooth-Hands-free-Transmitter-supported/dp/B000NVYVRO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NVYVRO)

Its a bluetooth A2DP hands free set and also has a USB port for charging your phone

Answer (score 0):

[ProClip](http://www.proclipusa.com/) has various solutions with cables, connectors, and specific car mounts. I've tried many of them, but use a TomTom car kit for navigation. But based on my experience ProClip is one of the best solution on the market today, with one minus: the price.

Answer (score 0):

[RoadTune Universal Hands-free Car Kit with FM Transmitter](http://www.lovecases.co.uk/roadtune-universal-hands-free-car-kit-with-fm-transmitter.html) features a 1 Amp USB Car Charger and FM Transmitter which enables you to wirelessly transmit music and hands-free calls from your iPhone through your car's stereo system.

See also this [video overview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCAyraXXU2E).